# Fifa 16 - PC -all players rendered black with Intel Iris Pro Graphics 580

Tags: pc, graphics-card, windows-10, fifa-16

I just bought the Intel NUC Skull Canyon (NUC6i7KYK) with the latest Iris Pro Graphics Card (580). As this is supposed to be a Mini PC for gaming, i expected FIFA 16 to be working. But unfortunately it is impossible to play, since all players are rendered black. Does anybody have an idea?

I tried all various display configurations, but none was working. I am using Windows 10 64 BIT. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: They look ok to me. Isn't it just shading on their playermodels?

Comment: exactly, with most of the display configurations of fifa they are completely black. the best it gets is with a frame rate set to "no limit on fps". this is the picture you see above. but players are still to dark to differentiate.

Comment: actually I reinstalled the intel drivers yesterday. after playing around with all the display configuration settings on fifa, it turns out they are still too dark to play, but not anylonger completely black. the issue remains :-(

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the lighting/shadow settings in game?

Comment: is there a setting like this in fifa 16? do you mean "video calibration"?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with the game itself. Try searching through the options menu and look for some lighting or shadows options. Remember to also search through advanced options if they are included.

Comment: as much as i've seen there is nothing like that in fifia 16 to adjust shadows. I tried to configure via Windows 10 and also via my monitor, but nothing helped. Actually when I lock the frame rate to 60 fps the players become red. when I lock to 30fps they become completely black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there were driver issues, a couple of days ago intel published a bunch of new drivers. now it works: https://communities.intel.com/thread/102774

**Update 1**

Just to make clear - this thread is about NUC6i7KYK with Intel Iris 580. With latest drivers it is working. Another user mentioned that this issue remains with Iris 550. So don't down vote if it not working on other intel graphics!